# TSQL: execute procedure with a parameter that can have two values

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

Hello all,

I want to execute the following procedure:

```
EXECUTE MYDB.dbo.MYPROCEDURE 
        @gender='male',
        @status='single'
```

The status can be single, divorced or married. 
I need to execute the procedure having all the males that are single and divorced.

Ho can I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to change your stored procedure over to a table-value function.  Then you could call it twice and UNION ALL the results to get one resultset.  The other way to do it would be to just call the stored procedure twice and add the results together yourself.

Unless you are fine with getting two resultsets back (by executing the statement twice), you will need to make some sort of modification to your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

That's just not possible unless you rewrite the procedure

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without changing the Procedure.

One option would be to set the value as `singledivorced` and have the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE [status]=@status
OR (@status='singledivorced' AND ([status]='single' or [status]='divorced'))
```